# Probability of $n$-th coordinate of vector of realistion of multivariate distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is random variable $X$ with $n$-dimensional normal distribution with mean $m$ and covariance matrix $cov$, we are given $x[-n]$  which are first $n-1$ coordinates of single realisation of random variable $X$, what is the probability that $n$-th coordinate ($x[n]$) is equal $y$ ?

I think that solution is density $d(y|x[-n]) = d(x)/d(x[-n])$

Comment: Unless the covariance matrix is positive definite, then it is $0$. Otherwise, your $X$ is degenerate and due to linear dependency, the probability is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Your answer is exactly right if you mean densities, not the probabilities. In this case $p(\bullet)$ should not be necessarily inside $(0,1)$ (neither $[0,1]$). Of course, all this works only in case of non-degenerate covariance matrix, as was mentioned by @Calculon.

Comment: yes I should ask about densities, but if p() is probality, why $p(y|[-n])$ is not necessarily inside $(0,1)$ ? its probability in the end ...